# A proposal for how to keep the Resources page uncluttered

Tags: discusión, formulado-de-preguntas

Some recent additions to the [Dictionaries section of the Resources page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/9385) are much more detailed than the rest of the page.  I don't want to lose all that information, so I'd like to see *some* of the details moved somewhere else, to keep the page streamlined.

I propose that the somewhere else be a Community Wiki type question along these lines:

> **How do online language dictionaries based on user contributions work?**
>
> Which online dictionaries can native and non-native speakers of Spanish, respectively, contribute to?  Please give an overview of how each category of speaker can contribute.

The recent participant's contributions would fit as an answer to this, I think.

The wording can be refined, of course.  But I'd like to get a green light from the community before posing a question of this type because it would be about learning resources, and this is a new area for us.

Another possible solution would be to post the question in Meta.  I would be okay with that if it's more comfortable for people.

I'm very open to any other suggestions people may have.

What I'm trying to avoid is telling the recent contributor to go post all those details in a blog somewhere and just link to that.  I would not view that as an acceptable solution in this case.

---

I just noticed that our Resources page already has the title "Resources for learning Spanish."  Therefore I will propose that we create a new, similar page, called "Resources for those who are fluent in Spanish."  Here are some examples of resources that would go in the new page:

(**Audio Pronunciation** could be left out)

**Corpora**

- all of these

**Dictionaries (online)**

- Monolingual (not bilingual ones)
- Specialized
- Other
- Let's restore linguee.com -- I love this for checking usage -- it shows quotes from published works

**Dictionaries (paper)**

- Moliner

**Lists of words**

- Maybe the 80K, maybe the one million -- I haven't quite understood how one uses these lists -- but not the 500 verbs or the difficult to pronounce

**Netflix**

- probably everything but I'm not a good person to judge about these

(note that I'm not sure if we need to be posting links to specific searches within Netflix -- why not just post an example of how to construct a search for film/TV of a particular country)

The three notes could be removed in my opinion.

**Other**

- Most of these would be okay I guess, but not "InterActive Terminology for Europe"

**Podcasts**

- Radio Ambulante
- A la Aventura

**Thesauri**

- both of these

**Websites**

- (none of these, I think)

Answer (score 2):

I got a new idea today, after seeing the veritable tsunami of new contributions to the Resources page.

How about we divide things up into two resources pages, as follows?

1. Resources for those learning Spanish as a second language
2. Resources for general Spanish speakers

Note that for example in the area of podcasts, Radio Ambulante would clearly go in #2, and possibly in #1, but pedagogical podcasts would only go in #1.

Comment: This also looks like a plan! Although the division between the two pages can be a bit fuzzy: where would you put links to the _Diccionario de americanismos_, for example?

Comment: @fedorqui - I agree there might be some fuzzy items; this one isn't fuzzy though, in my opinion: it's useful for people who aren't learning Spanish as a second language.  Your refining question has helped me delineate my proposal better.  I think that the flow chart should go like this: if it falls into #1, then it should go in #1; otherwise, it should go in #2.

Comment: i think general resources should be ALL the resources 
while specific resources only contain those for the specific purpose, 

tha's the reason i encourage individual pages for each subject, so we have only one location to store them, but referenced in a lot of different places without having to maintain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible to create an specific page for each resource and only have the link to that resource in the title ?

i.e:

Answers

> **Dictionaries online**
>
> *Link to dictionaries online*
>
> ---
>
> Audio Pronunciation
>
> Link to Audio Pronunciation
>
> ---

inside the new Dictionaries Online :

Question: **Dictionaries online**

> welcome to the Dictionaries Online wiki page, this page is to community wiki to share online dictionaries for the community
>
> ---
>
> answers:
>
> Monolingual dictionaries .......

the idea would be having only one question and one answer

this would also be helpful to link independent resources rather than linking the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea.  I'm not hugely in favor, though, because I like the way it's laid out now, with links at the top of the page to each specific section.

Comment: This may be an interesting idea! The Resources wiki page has grown so much that it is a bit of a _cajón de sastre_ nowadays.